# Memcached with local storage of variables, redundant?

Tags: php, memcached

I have a bit of a logical kalamdrum. 
We are migrating to a new server with php 5.6 from 5.3 and we are upgrading to cluster logic. 
It is planned min. 4 servers for now with one central memcache server wich will be called from all 4 of them (or 4 instances of memcache with shared key pool).

I am rewriting our old PhP handlers so they can work with that structure...

**Anyway, my problem is:** 
Schould i build a local variable storage in php to for the called variables to prevent double calls to the memcached or schold i just call the memcached? (foregt the ttl, they are on the same vm system)

ps. i mean like storing the get calls in a  key->variable way

Answer (score 1):

In our implementation (at http://www.gutefrage.net) we save them locally in PHP for the request, too. We have some sort of memcache caching layer in our PHP App. It has something todo with the performance. If thats not a Problem, dont do it, cause the complexity will increase.

Comment: Thank you :) i will test the performanse first. noted the added complexity.